# software for rational points on quartic plane curves

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-software

Faltings' theorem tells us the number of rational points on a smooth quartic plane curve is finite.

**Question**: Is there any software for computing all the rational points over $\mathbb{Q}$ on a given (smooth) quartic plane curve?

Answer (score 1):

There is the famous example of J.-P. Serre: determine all rational points on
$$
x^4 + y^4 = 17.
$$
I am not sure if it is solved. Of course, there are the obvious rational solutions, $(\pm 1,\pm 2)$ and $(\pm2,\pm1)$, but we (and you) want to know all rational solutions. 
In general, there is no software to determine this (there is "Sage", for example, for doing such computations, but it need not give all solutions).

Comment: It seems that Serre's problem has been settled by [E. Victor Flynn](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/257/1/art17.pdf)

Comment: @yzhao yes, thank you, I have seen it.