# Find rational numbers $(x,y)$ such that $ (x^2 + y^2 - 2x)^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, algebraic-curves

The general [limaçon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on) has both a polar equation: $r = b + a \cos \theta  $ and an algebraic equation:
$$ (x^2 + y^2 - ax)^2 = b^2 (x^2 + y^2)$$
Can we find all the rational points on a curve like this?

I want to consider the case $a = 2b$ and $b = 1$:
$$ (x^2 + y^2 - 2x)^2 = x^2 + y^2$$
One solution is $(x,y) = (0,1)$ and another is $(x,y) = (1,0)$. How can I generate the other solutions over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

[image: trisectrix limaçon]

Comment: Substitute x=a, some rational constant, to get a fourth order equation, which can be converted to a quadratic equation and find the necessary condition on 'a' to obtain, rational y values

Comment: This question/answer seems relevant, albeit lacking in a lot of details: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/550253/137524.

Comment: Take $y=\lambda x$ and factor out $x^2$ from both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cases in which $x$ or $y$ are $0$ are easily described, so suppose that neither are $0$.

Define $\lambda$ by $y=\lambda x$. Since $x,y\in \mathbb Q$, with neither of them equal to $0$, we see that $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$.

Your equation becomes $$\left( (1+\lambda^2)x^2-2x\right)^2=(1+\lambda^2)x^2$$

Divide through by $x^2$ to get $$\left( (1+\lambda^2)x-2\right)^2=(1+\lambda^2)\implies x=\frac {2\pm \sqrt {1+\lambda^2}}{1+\lambda^2}$$

We deduce that we are looking for $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$ such that $\sqrt {1+\lambda^2}\in \mathbb Q$. But taking any rational Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ gives the solution $\lambda =\frac ba$.  Conversely, given $\lambda=\frac mn\in \mathbb Q$ with $\sqrt {1+\lambda^2}=\frac rs\in \mathbb Q$, we have $$1+\frac {m^2}{n^2}=\frac {r^2}{s^2}\implies (ns)^2+(ms)^2=(rn)^2$$ so any rational point on your curve arises from a Pythagorean triple.

For example: starting with the triple $(3,4,5)$ gives us the solution $(\frac {33}{25},\frac {44}{25})$

Comment: It's essentially the same for arbitrary rational $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @egreg  Oh, agreed.

Comment: One observation: If the curve was smooth, then it being quartic would imply that it has only finitely many rational points (Faltings's theorem). But it's singular at the origin, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: despite being a quartic the lines intersect the curve at only 1 or 2 points how strange

Comment: @cactus314 Each line intersects $4$ times (over $\mathbb{C}$) if we count properly.  $(0,0)$ is a double point, so that accounts for $2$ intersections.  Then lulu found $2$ values for $x$ (assuming $1 + \lambda^2 \neq 0$), which brings the total to $4$.  When $1 + \lambda^2 = 0$, we also have the points $[1:\pm i: 0]$ at infinity.

Answer (score 4):

An even easier route for generating rational points is to start from the parametric equations of the limaçon: $\left((1+2\cos\theta)\cos\theta,(1+2\cos\theta)\sin\theta\right)^\top$, and then perform the Weierstrass substitution $\cos\theta\mapsto\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2},\;\sin\theta\mapsto\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$. Due to the nature of the substitution, you will not be able to obtain the point $(1,0)$, but all other rational points correspond to rational values of $u$.